# Is there a better way to restructure this array in Ruby?

Tags: arrays, ruby

I've got an array that looks like this:

```
{
    year_list: [{
        name: 2016,
        make_list: [{
            name: 'Honda',
            model_list: [{
                name: 'CRV',
                series_list: [{
                    name: 'Premium Plus',
                    style_list: [{
                        name: '4D SUV',
                        uvc: '123abc'
                    }]
                }]
            }]
        }]
    }]
}
```

And I want to transform this array to the following, where each combination of year, make, model, series and style combined into a hash and inserted into array.

```
 [{:year=> 2016,
  :make=>"Honda",
  :model=>"CRV",
  :series=>"Premium Plus",
  :style=>"4D SUV",
  :uvc=>"123abc"}]
```

I have a working solution, but I'm wondering if anyone has any ideas on how to make the solution more elegant solution.

```
list = []
year_list.each do |y_val|
  vehicle_type = {}
  vehicle_type[:year] = y_val['name']

  make_list = y_val['make_list']
  make_list.each do |k_val|
    vehicle_type[:make] = k_val['name']

    model_list = k_val['model_list']
    model_list.each do |m_val|
      vehicle_type[:model] = m_val['name']

      series_list = m_val['series_list']
      series_list.each do |s_val|
        vehicle_type[:series] = s_val['name']

        style_list = s_val['style_list']
        style_list.each do |st_val|
          vehicle_type[:style] = st_val['name']
          vehicle_type[:uvc] = st_val['uvc']
          list << vehicle_type
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Is there a way to utilize some of Ruby's array methods to make this a better solution?

**Edit: Here's a solution that is almost working using recursion.**

```
VEHICLES = []
ELEMENTS = [:year, :make, :model, :series, :style]

def walk_tree(arr, vehicle={})
  arr[0..1].each do |a|
    name = a['name']

    if a.key?('uvc')
      vehicle[:uvc] = a['uvc']
      VEHICLES << vehicle
      vehicle = {}
      next
    end

    ELEMENTS.each do |s|
      key = s.to_s + '_list'
      if a.key?(key)
        vehicle[s] = name
        walk_tree(a[key], vehicle)
      end
    end

  end
end

walk_tree(year_list)
pp LIST
```

Comment: Why is the `:uvc` included?

Comment: `uvc` is a unique identifier for every year, make, model, series, style combination. Unfortunately, this is the cruddy data structure this 3rd party API returns and why I'm trying to normalize it a bit.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to rewrite your solution without any additional accumulators or temporary variables which will shrink the number of code lines and make it clear. My solution uses only Array **map** method which will return desired result, but deeply wrapped into arrays. All external array wrappers can be removed with Array **flatten** method call.
Here is the output from irb console.

```
super_hash[:year_list].map do |year|
  year[:make_list].map do |make|
    make[:model_list].map do |model|
      model[:series_list].map do |series|
        series[:style_list].map do |style|
          {
            year: year[:name], 
            make: make[:name], 
            model: model[:name], 
            series: series[:name], 
            style: style[:name], 
            uvc: style[:uvc]
          }
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
#=> [[[[[{:year=>2016, :make=>"Honda", :model=>"CRV", :series=>"Premium Plus", :style=>"4D SUV", :uvc=>"123abc"}]]]]]
[[[[[{:year=>2016, :make=>"Honda", :model=>"CRV", :series=>"Premium Plus", :style=>"4D SUV", :uvc=>"123abc"}]]]]].flatten
#=> [{:year=>2016, :make=>"Honda", :model=>"CRV", :series=>"Premium Plus", :style=>"4D SUV", :uvc=>"123abc"}]
```

Answer (score 0):

You may recursively `inject`, passing all key-values as is, but looking for `_list` ones like this:

```
l = ->(h,(k,v)){
  if k =~ /(\w+)_list$/
    h[$1] = v.first[:name]
    return v.first.inject(h, &l)
  end
  h[k] = v
  h
}

p year_list.inject({}, &l)
```